# How to make if statement inside linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have following statement

```
Select(g => new AssembledPartsDTO
{
..
..
    References = g.SelectMany(entry => entry.References).OrderBy(t => t).ToList()
..
..
}
```

How I can add `if References.count == 0 than Add("??")` to `References`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your LINQ expression.

You could do something like this;

```
References = (g.SelectMany(entry => entry.References).Count() == 0)
   ? g.SelectMany(entry => entry.References).OrderBy(t => t).ToList() : null;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
References.count > 0 ? References : new List<string>(){"??"}
```

How about that

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
Select(g => 
{
   var obj = new AssembledPartsDTO { References= ... };
   if (obj.References.Count == 0)
   {  
      obj.References.Add("??");
   }

   return obj;
})
```

You may need this for a more complicated logic, where ternary operator ( ? ) does not apply.

Comment: It should be noted that this will work only for LINQ to Objects.